# Getting an 'undefined' error when using 'this' keyword

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

In My web application I need to create an instance of CKEditor. When I call the function I am using the `this` keyword which shows an 'undefined' exception. How can I call the `this` keyword? Where is my mistake? Is there another way to call the function instead of using the `this` keyword?

```html
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="940px" Height="400px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
        e.editor.document.on('keydown', function(event) {
            if (this.selectionStart == 0) {
                //something
            }    
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this. Thank you

Comment: what is the `this` that you refer to? which object you trying to access?

Comment: Hi, I need to access the `function event` i am trying when i enter text in ck editor i need first letter should be capital letter.Thank you

Comment: so just use the `event` variable...

Comment: your saying instead of `this` using `event` ok i will try that one

Comment: I asked you what you expect `this` to be, and you said you expect it to be the function event, so you can just use the `event` variable...

Answer (score 0):

try to get it by id instead of this keyword something like

`if ( $( "#CKEditor1" ).selectionStart == 0 )`

Comment: Thank you for giving me response. I tried your code but it shows always "0" only it will not increment.Can you please tell me

Comment: Change your event eg: onFocus , onClick

Comment: i am not getting what your saying can you please explain clearly

Comment: change your keydown down event to onClick   e.editor.document.on('onClick ', function(event))

Comment: i am trying for when i enter text in ckeditor first letter should be capital letter but in my code i am getting `this.selectionStart` is undefined. please tell me how to do this.Thank you

Comment: I am not sure it will work or not can you please check this $('#CKEditor1')[0].selectionStart; and let me know

Comment: `  if ($('#CKEditor1')[0].selectionStart == 0 && event.data.$.keyCode >= 65 && event.data.$.keyCode <= 90 && !(event.data.$.shiftKey) && !(event.data.$.ctrlKey) && !(event.data.$.metaKey) && !(event.data.$.altKey))
                        {
                            var $t = $('#CKEditor1')[0].selectionStart; 
                            event.data.$.preventDefault();
                            var char = String.fromCharCode(event.data.$.keyCode);
 $t.val(char + $t.val().slice(this.selectionEnd));
   this.setSelectionRange(1,1);
                        }`

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this . Thank you